# Grouping items in a reactive stream

Tags: java, spring-webflux, project-reactor

Say that I have a finite stream of these objects

```
class Item {
    private int id;
    private List<Tag> tags;
}
```

```
Flux<Item> publisher;
```

Say that these are the items in the stream:

```
[
    {"id": 1, "tags": [{"value":"A"}]},
    {"id": 2, "tags": [{"value":"B"}]},
    {"id": 2, "tags": [{"value":"C"}]},
]
```

I want to group them by id and join the corresponding values together.

```
[
    {"id": 1, "tag": [{"value":"A"}]},
    {"id": 2, "tag": [{"value":"B"}, {"value":"C"}]},
]
```

How can I do this on the publisher

Answer (score 1):

You can use `collectMultimap` which allows you to have `Map<K, Collection<T>>`:

```
publisher.collectMultimap(Item::getId)
     .subscribe(groupById -> System.out.println(groupById.toString()));
```

Output:

```
{1=[{"value":"A"}], 2=[{"value":"B"}, {"value":"C"}]}
```